# Mongo DB nested $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following code and iam trying to do nested `$lookup`. Ive seen similar questions but none worked.

```js
const clientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  suites: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Suite' }],
});
```

```js
const suiteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
});
```

```js
const floorPortSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  site: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Site' },
  suite: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Suite', default: null },
  device: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Device' },
  portNumber: { type: Number },
});
```

```js
const deviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  snmpCommunity: { type: String },
  deviceNumber: { type: Number, default: null },
});
```

```js
 Client.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(clientId),
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'suites',
          let: { suites: '$suites' },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$suites'] } },
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'floorports',
                let: { floorports: '$floorports' },
                pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$suite', '$$floorports'] } } }],
                as: 'floorports',
              },
            },
          ],
          as: 'suites',
        },
      },
    ])
```

what iam trying to achieve is following:

```json
{
    "name": "Some Client name",
    "suites": [
      {
        "_id": "601288c7e6203f167879aa91",
        "inUse": true,
        "occupant": "604635e3e043f344901804b8",
        "name": "101",
        "siteId": "600816a7943f700b64dfc0ee",
        "dateCreatedAt": "2021-01-28T09:49:59.735Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "workstations": 1,
        "floorports": [
          {
            "_id": "613092aae09028491453d4e0",
            "device": {
              _id: "605b1654f960f528b0c3cb1f"
              ....some other info
},
        }
     ]
}
```

But all i get is suites displayed correctly and each have floorports array but its empty. Anyone can help? Iam missing something in plain sight but cant figure out what :-(